# Unable to edit SSRS subcription list

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-2012, msbi

I am trying to edit the existing subscription list of the SSRS Reports.
However, I am getting below error when I click on Edit...

Can anyone has an idea\solution about this error ?

Thank You in Advance !!!
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution for this error.
This error generated due to default parameters was not set for the report.
To create a subscription for the ssrs report, the default parameters must be set. 
This can be set using report-manage-parameters...

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a matrix in a list in your report? Could it be this?

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/978636?wa=wsignin1.0

Comment: Hi, unfortunately this not helped :( I found the solution... Thanks :)